# New alert is not being called after if-statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I want a user to have the option to change his password. So first he has the first alert, where he has an input for his old pw, and one to repeat it ones. Then a new alert should follow immediately where he can input his new password twice. But this alert is never being called. I wonder if the error lies in the if statement, but I think I've done all correctly there, so far.

## page.ts

```
public password1 = '';
public password2 = '';

constructor(public alertController: AlertController) {}

async changePw() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Change your Password?',
      message: 'Type in your old password?',
       inputs: [
      {
        name: 'password1',
        placeholder: 'Old password',
        type: 'password'

      },
      {
        name: 'password2',
        placeholder: 'Repeat old password',
        type: 'password'
      }
    ],
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: data => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Submit',
        handler: async data => {
          if (this.password1 === this.password2 && this.password2 !== '') {
            const alert2 =  await this.alertController.create({
              header: 'Change your Password?',
              message: 'Type in your old password?',
               inputs: [
              {
                name: 'password3',
                placeholder: 'New password',
                type: 'password'
        
              },
              {
                name: 'password4',
                placeholder: 'Repeat new password',
                type: 'password'
              }
            ]
            });
            await alert2.present();
          } else {
            // invalid pw
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is your entire code or if you're just looking for the logic handling.

But I think the main problem is that you not use the data you get back from the alert controller. so check the use of data on the submit button handler. using data.password1 in this example the name you gave the input field, you can test the inputs.

So in your code, the `password2 !== ""` was always false because your not setting it.

you still, however, have to incorporate the old password into this function.

```
const alert1 = await this.aAlertController.create({
            header: 'Change your Password?',
            message: 'Type in your old password?',
             inputs: [
            {
              name: 'password1',
              placeholder: 'Old password',
              type: 'password'

            },
            {
              name: 'password2',
              placeholder: 'Repeat old password',
              type: 'password'
            }
          ],
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Cancel',
              role: 'cancel',
              handler: data => {
                console.log('Cancel clicked');
              }
            },
            {
              text: 'Submit',
              handler: data => {
                if (data.password1 === data.password2 && data.password2 !== '') {
                  const alert2 =  this.aAlertController.create({
                    header: 'Change your Password?',
                    message: 'Type in your old password?',
                     inputs: [
                    {
                      name: 'password3',
                      placeholder: 'New password',
                      type: 'password'

                    },
                    {
                      name: 'password4',
                      placeholder: 'Repeat new password',
                      type: 'password'
                    }
                  ]
                  });
                  alert2.present();
                } else {
                  // invalid pw
                  return false;
                }
              }
            }
          ]
          });

          await alert1.present();
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is my whole code for this functionality. When I implement your solution, I get this error: `alert2.present is not a function. (In 'alert2.present()', 'alert2.present' is undefined)` should `await alert1.present();` come before `alert2.present();` ?

Comment: Could you possibly create a codepen of your code, because the code as it is, is working on my side?

It doesn`t matter if alert2 is called before the first alert is presented, as long as it is called after the second alert is created.

Also if this is your whole code you should still test somewhere if the password inserted in the alert is the same as the stored password

Comment: Your function might be running asynchronously, try adding the async to the handler, and await on the alert2 create.